# How to log out user when url is changed from browser address bar

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using a spring mvc application (ABC application) with jsp as view technology.

I have a requirements as follows:

1. User open browser(any browser)
2. Enter URL of ABC application.
3. Log page of ABC application displayed
4. User log in ABC application
5. The home page of ABC application displayed
6. User change address of ABC application to www.google.com in the same
   tab and click enter.
7. Google page is diplayed.
8. User click back button on the browser and the home page of ABC
   application is displayed again

.

Expected result:

When user click back button the login page is displayed instead of the home page of ABC application.

So is there a way to identify that the user have edited the URL from the current tab of the browser so that I can call the log out method
from my controller?

Any advice/example that can point me to the right direction is most welcome.

Thanks again.

Comment: Please use proper tags. this has nothing to do with jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0):

From you app you can not know what user entered in web browser bar. What you can do is to define small session time-out for example 3 minutes in web.xml

```
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>3</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

This means if there is not action on web page for 3 minutes from logged user, next time user access to the page spring security(if you using that for your user management, and it is recommended if you already use spring mvc) will show log in page.